# How are the floats (0.0 to 1.0) mapped to ints (0 to 255) for pixel colors?

Tags: image, color

I'm fighting somewhat with Blenders image creation module. I struggle to map my calculated colors to the required range from 0.0 to 1.0. I need it to be very precise.

For example: I have a value 0.5 that will result in a value of 128 in the related color channel of the image. Then I have a value of 0.50390625 that I expected to result in 129, but becomes a 128 as well. Is there a formula or a list somewhere that shows exactly what ranges of floats are mapped to what integers? Or maybe someone can point me to the source-files, then I'd try to figure it out by myself. (I tried to locate the source file for this module but couldnt find it.)

Comment: Hi. How are you setting the colours? With code (if so, then please show the code) or via the UI?

Comment: Hello Ray, I'm tryin to export simple 3d-models into a texture. The xyz coords of the vertices will become the rbg values of the textures (this format is used in some virtual worlds). For example a value for a color channel is calulated like this: tmpx = (vert.co.x + (boundingBoxSize/2) - xrange) / boundingBoxSizeX

Comment: If that code is relevant to your question I suggesting adding that in.

Comment: its not relevant, since I would like to know how the Blenders image module turns floats into integers :)